# How to update a row in a List when data of that row changes?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

I have a list of objects that populate a list. The objects contain an icon that are loaded separately on demand.

Since the list is populated before all the icons are loaded I need to update the list row when the icon is ready.

```
// iirc it was something like this
var itemIndex:int = list.dataProvider.getItemIndex(item);
list.updateRow(itemIndex); // or list.redrawRow()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can use the following:

```
var itemIndex:int = itemsList.dataProvider.getItemIndex(item);

if (itemIndex!=-1) {
    var renderer:IItemRenderer = itemsList.dataGroup.getElementAt(itemIndex) as IItemRenderer;

    if (renderer) {
        itemsList.updateRenderer(renderer, itemIndex, item);
    }
}
```